# MySql TIMESTAMP error: Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp, sql-insert, mysql-error-1064

I have a table like this:

```
    CREATE TABLE event (
                       id              BIGINT          NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,

                       name            VARCHAR(80)     NOT NULL,                       
                       start_datetime  TIMESTAMP       NOT NULL DEFAULT '1970-01-01 00:00:01',
                       end_datetime    TIMESTAMP       NOT NULL DEFAULT '1970-01-01 00:00:01',

                       description     TEXT,                      

                       created         TIMESTAMP(3)    NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3),
                       modified        TIMESTAMP(3)    NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3) ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3)

);
```

There is no error when this new record is inserted:

```
insert into event (name, start_datetime, end_datetime)
value
('myName', '2020-01-05 18:00:00', '2020-01-07 23:59:00')
;
```

But this record is throwing error:

```
insert into event (name, start_datetime, end_datetime)
value
('myName', '2045-01-05 18:00:00', '2045-01-07 23:59:00')
;
```

The error is

```
Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: '2045-01-05 18:00:00' for column 'start_datetime' at row 1
```

Could anyone please help ?
Thanks so much!

Updated:
Found this in MySql document:
The TIMESTAMP data type is used for values that contain both date and time parts. TIMESTAMP has a range of '1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC to '2038-01-19 03:14:07' UTC.

So I guess 2045 is too far away ... ...

Comment: So you found the answer by yourself. You might as well post this as an answer, since you were actually first!

Answer (score 10):

`TIMESTAMP` is only vaild for

> The TIMESTAMP data type is used for values that contain both date and time parts. TIMESTAMP has a range of '1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC to '2038-01-19 03:14:07' UTC.

For "bigger" Dates switch to DATETIME

> the range for DATETIME values is '1000-01-01 00:00:00.000000' to '9999-12-31 23:59:59.999999'

For more information consult the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html)

Answer (score 2):

From the [MySQL documentation](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-timestamp.aspx)

> The TIMESTAMP value has a range from '1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC to '2038-01-19 03:14:07' UTC.

The issue is that the year 2045 is not allowed for the `TIMESTAMP` column.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own(as in updated section of the original question)
Found this in MySql document: The TIMESTAMP data type is used for values that contain both date and time parts. TIMESTAMP has a range of '1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC to '2038-01-19 03:14:07' UTC.